# what's with all of these errors?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ProfileViewController : UIViewController {
    UIImageView *profPic;
    UILabel *name;
    UILabel *hosted;
    UILabel *points;
    UILabel *attended:
    UITableView *tableView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView profPic;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel hosted;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel points;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel attended:
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView tableView;

@end
```

Comment: What errors? I can't see any errors? All I see is source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

those UI* objects should be pointers:

```
IBOutlet UIImageView * profPic;
```

Answer (score 2):

Although you have not posted what exactly errors you get there're 2 obvious problems in your code:

1. Colon in the end of the line should be semicolon:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel attended:
                                                         ^^^
   ```
2. Types of properties should be pointers ('*' missed in property declarations)

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel* attended;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *profPic;
```

Add the Asterisk(*) before the name of the object.